# Amazon API Gateway sending event to Lambda with wrong structure. event.body is undefined

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have an API Gateway launching my Lambda function (not as a proxy integration). I have the following Mapping template:

```
{
  "body": $input.json('$'),
  "headers": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().header.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().header.get($param))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  },
  "pathParameters": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().path.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().path.get($param))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  },
  "queryStringParameters": {
    #foreach($param in $input.params().querystring.keySet())
    "$param": "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params().querystring.get($param))"
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  }
}
```

In my Lambda function, I am doing:

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);
    console.log(event.body);
    console.log(event.headers);
}
```

Logging this in Cloudwatch, I get:

```
{ bodyParam1 : bodyValue1, bodyParam2 : bodyValue2 }
undefined
undefined
```

Looking at the `context` instead, I get:

```
{
  callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop: [Getter/Setter],
  succeed: [Function (anonymous)],
  fail: [Function (anonymous)],
  done: [Function (anonymous)],
  functionVersion: '$LATEST',
  functionName: 'MyFunctionName',
  memoryLimitInMB: '2048',
  logGroupName: '/aws/lambda/MyFunctionName',
  logStreamName: '2023/11/30/[$LATEST]901a95627c014546a8c787e85772a4c9',
  clientContext: undefined,
  identity: undefined,
  invokedFunctionArn: 'arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-1:041265341671:function:MyFunctionName',
  awsRequestId: '17bbcd5f-b221-411f-a7d5-90bd44dc2bbf',
  getRemainingTimeInMillis: [Function: getRemainingTimeInMillis]
}
```

Why is the `event` in this structure? How do I access my headers?